# How to change fixed header in jquery mobile dynamically

Tags: android, jquery, ios, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have a fixed header in a Jquery mobile & Cordova powered app. So `data-position="fixed"`

```
<div data-position="fixed" data-role="header" data-theme='b' id="mainHeader">
    <h1>XXXXXXXXXX</h1>
    <img src="img/banner.png" style="width:100%;" />

    <div style="height:40px; width:100%; text-align:center; font-size:20px; background-color:#809710;">
    Welcome
    </div>
</div><!--Header-->
```

Big header isn't it! :) Now when the mobile orientation is changed, that means when it goes to portrait to landscape I want to change this `data-position` so that this shouldn't be fixed anymore. Then again when it came back to portrait it should again be fixed.

I can control the changing orientation detection. Problem is how can I change this data-position attribute and make this fixed or not fixed.

I tried

```
var col = $('#mainHeader');
col.data('position','');
```

Didn't work. Can anyone please help to achieve this??

**Update:**  [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gsujU/)

Comment: Try to add col.trigger('pagecreate') after new styles applying

Comment: @Regent Tried not working http://jsfiddle.net/gsujU/

Comment: which jQM version are you using?

Comment: @Omar 1.4.0. Problem solved already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$(document).on('click', "#btn", function () {
    alert("OK");
    $('#mainHeader').removeClass('ui-header-fixed');

});
$(document).on('click', "#abtn", function () {
    alert("OK");
    $('#mainHeader').addClass('ui-header-fixed');

});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gsujU/1/)

Comment: Nope, Header isn't moving. Still acting as fixed.